# problema com routes laravel 7.0 hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

Opa! Primeiramente seu meio leigo ainda no laravel 
consegui colocar em produção(servidor compartilhado cpanel locaweb) porem funciono em partes o índex fico top consultando o banco usando multTenant so que as **demais rotas não funciona**.
Achei que era algo relacionado ao Middleware do Tenant, mas não pois fiz uma rota retornando um direto (para teste claro rs) e isolei do Middleware porem sem sucesso
minha estrutura deixei assim
pasta Laravel na raiz da hospedagem (/) e os arquivos do public dentro de public_html
alterei os arquivos necessários do index.php e do serve.php.

porem notei uma coisa que não sei dizer se é certa ou não posso colocar qualquer coisa no server.php ele não altera em nada no projeto coloquei ate um dd(); dentro porem nem chega a entrar dentro dele.

recursos utilizados:
servidor Locaweb compartilhado Cpanel sem acesso SSH/terminal
Laravel 7.0, mysql, PHP 7.2 (ea-php72)

vocês teria alguma ideia de o que esta acontecendo ou se seria algum erro meu mesmo? ou outra maneira de fazer

Answer (score 0):

Você deve apontar a pasta raiz do projeto sendo a `/public`. Deve haver alguma opção dentro do Cpanel para definir qual a pasta raiz.

Caso não ache, dá sim para mover os arquivos da pasta `public` para a `public_html`. Para isso, você simplesmente arrasta e nos caminhos dentro dos arquivos, como por exemplo o caminho dentro de **Index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

deve ser mudado para:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Você deve mudar o caminho de todos os arquivos que você mover